# MPI_Init_thread function was called before MPI_Init was invoked

Tags: fortran, mpi, openmp, gfortran, openmpi

I need an MPI_Init_Thread  call example in fortran.

I tried it without MPI_Init before it and got the message:"MPI_Init_thread function was called before MPI_Init was invoked".

I called after MPI_init and got the message "Calling MPI_Init or MPI_Init_Thread twpce is erreneous." altough I had each called once.

I am confused.

Also are there three or 4 arguments?  and what are they? I believe it is three and the second one I want is MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE but program aborts.

It would be best if someone uses it with fortran could post an example call please.

For completeness I am posting a simple code I am tring to run in hybrid (MPI + OPENMP) mode.
My purpose is to run this job on two nodes , each with 32 threads by making use of openmp within each node.

```
program hello

Use mpi

integer ierr,np,pid,inull1,inul2,hug


    call MPI_Init(ierr)


   inull2=3

!    call MPI_Init_thread(inull1,inull2,ierr)

    call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, pid,ierr)

    call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, np, ierr)


    write(6,*) 'inull2,MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE',MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE


 hug=huge(inull1)



!$OMP PARALLEL SHARED(inull1,inull2,hug,MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE,np) &
 
!$OMP          PRIVATE(pid)
 
!$OMP DO SCEDULE (STATIC)
  


 do i=1,hug

    write(6,*) 'program hello_world i,np,pid,inull2,mtm',i,np,pid,inull2,MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE

 enddo

!$OMP END DO

!$OMP END PARALLEL



    call MPI_Finalize(ierr)


end program hello
```

I compile it with

```
      mpif90 -o hello_world_openmp.exe hello_world_openmp.f90
```

and run it with the following command (for now)

```
      mpirun -hostfile hostfile -pernode -bind-to none hello_world_openmp.exe
```

Changing the code as

integer ierr,np,pid,inull1,inul2,hug

!    call MPI_Init(ierr)

```
call MPI_Init_thread(MPI_THREAD_FUNNELLED,inull2,ierr)
```

---

also gives the following error:
*** The MPI_Init_thread() function was called before MPI_INIT was invoked.
*** This is disallowed by the MPI standard.
*** Your MPI job will now abort.

Comment: Hi n.gul, welcome to Stack Overflow :) I'm afraid your question as written is not a good fit for the [question and answer format](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) we prefer around here. However, it shouldn't be too hard to turn your question [into that format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): you say "I tried it without MPI_Init before"; could you give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you tried?

Comment: Please do not completely rewrite your answer so that all errors are gone and you have no question any more. Also, even when you do revise, please format the code appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The error message you quite is strange. But it has been reported before (https://www.mail-archive.com/devel@lists.open-mpi.org/msg19978.html https://github.com/TRIQS/cthyb/issues/122)

It points to some incompatibility somewhere. In your case it points to an incorrect call to MPI_Init_thread. The main point is:

### Always use `IMPLICIT NONE`!

This cannot be over-stressed. Even in a very short code you must use it. You declared `inul2` instead of `inull2` and you used `MPI_THREAD_FUNNELLED` instead of `MPI_THREAD_FUNNELED`. After correcting that, your codes runs correctly for me.

---

One calls `MPI_Init_thread` instead of `MPI_Init`, not after.

You call it like

```
call MPI_Init_thread(required, provided, ie)
```

where all arguments are integers, `required` is an input argument saying which threading level you need and `provided` is an output argument and says which threading level you got.

Be aware that for many MPI implementations `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE` is either not supported at all or is very slow. I suggest designing your programs without the need for `MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE`.

The usage can be something like

```
    integer :: ie
    integer :: required, provided

    required = MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED
  
    call MPI_Init_thread(required, provided, ie)

    if (ie/=0) ... error

    if (provided<required) then
       ... different error
```

Comment: Which MPI library version are you using?

Comment: Please do not use comments for code, the code cannot be read there. You have to edit your question, if the code is important (it probably is).

Comment: I repeat, do not use comments for code and other important information. Edit your question.

Comment: OpenMPI 1.10 is extremely old. You should use something more recent. OpenSUSE 15.x or SLE contain packages for HPC modules with OpenMPI versions up to 4.

Comment: These very comments below my answer and below your question are comments. Do not use them for code, go under your question, where *Share
Edit
Follow
Close
Flag* is
and click on **Edit**. Please take the [tour] to see how to use this site.